# How to pass "mysql_native_password" to MySQL service in GitHub Actions?

Tags: mysql, docker, github-actions

Example of my GitHub Action config:

```
jobs:
  unit-test:
    name: Unit Testing
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: db
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=5
    steps:
      - name: Verify MySQL connection from host
        run: mysql --host mysql --port 3306 -uroot -ppassword -e "SHOW DATABASES"
```

With MySQL 5.7 it works. But with MySQL 8.0 it shows:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: ...
```

In MySQL docker docs there is a line which allows `mysql_native_password` auth:

```
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

How to allow the `mysql_native_password` auth plugin in GitHub Actions/service?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is that GH actions does not move `--entrypoint` option and related arguments to the end of the command but instead it appends other options like env. variables specified in `env` `service` section after it.

After a lot of trial and errors I found out, you can specify the env. vars manually, command like this is working:

```
...
    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:8
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=5 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxx -e MYSQL_USER=xxx -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxx -e MYSQL_DATABASE=xxx --entrypoint sh mysql:8 -c "exec docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
    steps:
...
```

Comment: As nobody has raised the issue with GitHub, I've added it to https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/711. It looks like the plugin can be used with RAW SQL too. I'm going to make an alternative answer with that using just a SQL file in the standard folder structure if I can get it to work.

Comment: This will cause `Error: Failed to initialize, mysql service is unhealthy. ` on my end.

Comment: @ChenglongMa check https://github.com/atk4/data/blob/3.0.0/.github/workflows/test-unit.yml for a working example

Comment: Thank you @mvorisek!! I finally used the `bitnami/mysql` as mentioned by @Aszen below.

Answer (score 8):

Currently its not possible to specify command option in github actions service workflow syntax, a simpler alternative is to use a different mysql image and override the entrypoint to use native password, or use an existing image that provides configuring auth method using env variables like this bitnami mysql image.

Using the bitnami mysql image:

```
    services:
      mysql:
        image: bitnami/mysql:8.0.20
        env:
          ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: yes
          MYSQL_DATABASE: abc
          MYSQL_AUTHENTICATION_PLUGIN: mysql_native_password
        ports:
          - 3306/tcp
        options: >-
          --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" 
          --health-interval=10s 
          --health-timeout=5s 
          --health-retries=3
```